# Dictionary items that update themselves when called in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Would it be possible to set up a dictionary so that the items update themselves when called through their key?

Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
 
 
color_it = cycle('rbg') #i want the color to go from red to blue to green

PARAMS = { # dict that hold all the parameters
"fc" : next(color_it),
         }

Data = {1:1,2:2,3:3}
for k,it in Data.items() :
    plt.bar(k,it,**PARAMS) #here i want the "next" function 
    #to be called on the iterator
```

However everything is red (because `next` will only be called during initialization). I want the dictionary items to be updated before I pass it to `plt.bar`.

Is the behavior I ask for possible?

It would be great for plotting larger datasets while controlling the aspect.

Comment: Just implement your own [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping), then `__getitem__` can do whatever you like.

Comment: you could put a function in a dictionary but you'd have to call it to receive a value `dic["key"]()`

Comment: Do you add keys to the dictionary once on initialisation only?  You could initialise it via a comprehension `PARAMS = {key: value for key, value in zip(cycle('rgb'), ["fc", ...])}`

Comment: @Anentropic I want to have the same dictionary for each time i use it in plt.bar, with only the fc item updating itself and returning the next item in the iterator

Comment: @jonrsharpe i'm not familliar with Mapping, will i be able to pass it as a dict for kwargs ?

Comment: `Mapping` is the generic interface of which `dict` is one implementation, yes it can be `**kw` unpacked.

Comment: @ZubBat it'd be a good idea to try to explain that part more clearly in the question, because I think the suggestions in comments so far do not give you that, because it was hard to understand what you really wanted